# Modelling object-oriented program in Coq

Tags: oop, graph, coq

I want to prove some facts about imperative object-oriented program. How can I represent a heterogeneous object graph in Coq? My main problem is that edges are implicit - each node consists of an integer label modelling object address and a data structure that models object state. So implicit edges are formed by fields inside data structure that model object pointers and contain address label of another node in a graph. To ensure that my graph is valid, adding new node to the graph must require a proof that all fields in a data structure that is being added refer to nodes that already exist in the graph. But how can I express 'all pointer fields in a data structure' in Coq?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you represent a data structure, and what kinds of features the language you want to model has. Here's one possibility. Let's say that your language has two kinds of values: numbers and object references. We can write this type in Coq as:

```
Inductive value : Type :=
| VNum (n : nat)
| VRef (ref : nat).
```

A reference (or pointer) is just a natural number that can be used to uniquely identify objects on the heap. We can use functions to represent both objects and the heap as follows:

```
Definition object : Type := string -> option value.
Definition heap : Type := nat -> option object.
```

Paraphrasing in English, an object is a partial function from strings (which we use to model fields in the object) to values, and a heap is a partial function from nats (that is, object references) to objects. We can then express your property as:

```
Definition object_ok (o : object) (h : heap) : Prop :=
  forall (s : string) (ref : nat),
    o s = Some (VRef ref) ->
    exists obj, h ref = Some obj.
```

Again, in English: if the field `s` of the object `o` is defined, and equal to a reference `ref`, then there exists some object `obj` stored at that address on the heap `h`.

The one problem with that representation is that Coq functions make it possible for heaps to have infinitely many objects, and objects to have infinitely many fields. You can circumvent this problem with an alternative representation that only allows for functions defined on finitely many inputs, such as lists of pairs, or (even better) a type of finite maps, such as [this one](https://github.com/arthuraa/coq-utils/blob/master/theories/partmap.v).