# How to prove properties with Object Oriented concepts in Coq

Tags: coq

Sometimes I have codes based on O.O. Concepts such as classes and interfaces. For example, a student object has two nat numbers, one for his student number and one for his GPA.

```
 public class Student {
    // The private instance variables
    private int studentNumber;
    private int GPA;             
    }
```

Is there any way to code these concepts in Coq? Thank you for your guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coq has records to model sets of fields:

```
Record student : Set := mkStudent {
  studentNumber : string;
  gpa           : string
}.
```

You can model alternatives and sub-classing with inductive types:

```
Inductive person : Set :=
  | Student : student -> person
  | Teacher : teacher -> person.
```

And, of course methods can be modelled as functions:

```
Definition age (p: person) : nat :=
  match p with
  | Student s => ..
  | Teacher t => ..
```

Although this is not the cleanest way, and in-place modification (mutability) need to be handled through monads; it can work.

Keep in mind that for complete proofs you need to provide mapping to your OOP model and proving that the mapping is correct/sound.

Comment: Also, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796264/modelling-object-oriented-program-in-coq

Comment: Thank you, mpetruska. Can you write about or provide me a reference for what you mean by in-place modification (mutability) and mapping to my OOP model. I'm grateful.

Comment: In java for example this method modifies a field's value in the current object: `public void setNumber(string newValue) { this.studentNumber = newValue }`. In pure functional programming all values are immutable, instead you can create a function the generates a new record with the updated field: `withNumber : student -> string -> student`